# Can I set up two different wireless APs, each with a different SSID, to the same DSL modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn

I've been using a VPN for a little while now and I would like to take it to the next level by setting up a wireless router that will automatically tunnel all traffic through my VPN. The problem is that the VPN kills my ping/response times for multiplayer gaming.

I would like to setup my hardware so that I can have two different logical networks that client devices such as my computer can choose from. One network would go through the VPN, the other would be normal. I would like to do this using a single DSL modem.

I have this networking diagram in mind.

Is this possible? If not, is there an easier way do what I want? I would prefer that any solution be network based, and not just based on a software configuration on my PC.

[image: network diagram showing two APs and one modem]

Key points:

- DSL modem is combination modem/wireless AP and has basic routing features and four ethernet ports
- I don't want to replace my DSL modem unless I have to
- I am willing to purchase a couple of inexpensive wireless routers. I have one in mind that I know supports DD-WRT, and I know that my VPN provider has a DD-WRT configuration available to set the router to tunnel all traffic through the VPN.

Comment: I see no reason why this wouldn't work, although you would have two routers back to back on either network, so you would essentially be double NATing which can cause havoc with gaming. Is your DSL modem/router capable of "bridge mode" or passing through it's public IP address without routing it? If so, a single quality DD-WRT (with VPN options) router (thinking Asus AC1900 or similar) could handle both functions via VLANing and multiple SSID's and have no issues with NAT translation.

Comment: @acejavelin Thanks. I checked on my modem and it does support transparent bridging, which I think describes what you are referring to. However, I haven't been able to find any information on setting up a DD-WRT router that has a VPN only configured to one VLAN but not the others. Any ideas on what I should read to get started with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can buy a cheap router that supports the Tomato firmware or DD-WRT and set up Virtual Wireless on it.

[Setup a Guest Network for Guest WiFi with Tomato VLAN](https://learntomato.com/setup-guest-network-guest-wifi-tomato-vlan/)
[Multiple WLANs](https://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Multiple_WLANs) tutorial from DD-WRT

Comment: Problem with this solution is that it does not handle the VPN routing aspect of the problem, which is a key requirement.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. But if you mean to say that one wireless network should go through the VPN, here's from the mentioned DD-WRT guide "You may also bridge a VLAN or VPN tunnel interface to the virtual wireless interface."

Answer (score 0):

What you have proposed can work, except instead of using an Access Point B, you need to use a router/AP B.  (You could get away with an AP for A though!).  The point being you need a router so that traffic can be ROUTED through the VPN.

This solution is less then ideal from the POV of sharing the available WIFI bandwidth but it can work.

Another alternative would be to have a single router and use IP based routing (easy) or policy based routing (hard) to use a single router to direct traffic appropriately down the VPN or regular Internet connection depending on the traffic.  This is nice because its totally seemless from the POV of your phones/computers.   The difficulty is working out how to pick up and direct the traffic, which will depend on the games.

Comment: Thanks. The difficulty of using a policy based routing is the main reason why I was looking for a solution involving multiple networks. I'm not too concerned about bandwidth aspect. I appreciate you point out that I need a router/AP and not just a router for B. I actually already have this picked out, as I'm using the one recommended by my VPN provider. Is there any specific type of networking connection I need to configure to connect two different routers to my DSL modem (bridging, ad-hoc, etc), or should it pretty much work out of the box (assuming I set up the VPN on the router correctly).